# MySQLselect distinct player that has no need score track row in 24 hours

Tags: mysql

My system inserts a score number for every player that wants to track his score every 24 hours from his last track.

I basically insert a score into the `tracks` table with player name, score and current timestamp.

I want to select ALL players that hasn't been tracked in at-least 24 hours.

Here's my attempt:

```
`SELECT distinct player_name FROM tracks WHERE creation_date < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)`;
```

But it seems to return the player in all cases, maybe I am not understanding something well.

Seems like I have to run select in select, to select the most recent track, and check if its older than 24 hours?

Comment: `WHERE creation_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` is helpful ?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting unwanted players, because there may be players that have records older than 24 hours and records newer, such as :

```
player_name | creation_date
------------+--------------
 'Foo'      | 1970-01-01     <-- WHERE creation_date < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) matches this
 'Foo'      | 2019-04-04     <-- Today
```

To fix that, you can do the opposite, getting the list of players that have a less than 24 hours record. Then you can use that result to get the list of players that aren't in the list.

In example :

```
SELECT DISTINCT player_name
FROM tracks
WHERE player_name NOT IN
(
    SELECT player_name
    FROM tracks 
    WHERE creation_date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
);
```

Another way to get this would to use a `GROUP BY player_name` along with a `HAVING MAX ...` clause, such as :

```
SELECT player_name
FROM tracks
GROUP BY player_name
HAVING MAX(creation_date) < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

---

Try it yourself :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE tracks (
  `player_name` VARCHAR(5),
  `creation_date` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO tracks
  (`player_name`, `creation_date`)
VALUES
  ('Foo', '1970-01-01'),
  ('Foo', DATE(NOW())),
  ('Bar', DATE(NOW())),
  ('Bob', '2019-03-03'),
  ('Bob', '2019-02-02');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT player_name
FROM tracks
WHERE player_name NOT IN
(
    SELECT player_name
    FROM tracks 
    WHERE creation_date >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
);
```

**Output**

```
| player_name |
| ----------- |
| Bob         |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT player_name
FROM tracks
GROUP BY player_name
HAVING MAX(creation_date) < DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

**Output**

```
| player_name |
| ----------- |
| Bob         |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a1ZAP9rL6wMpKCjRh8joKT/1)